# How to get recordId of row on mouseover in lightning-datatable LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, popover, mousehover

How to get recordId of row on mouseover in lightning-datatable LWC.
event.detail is coming as 0.
I need this feature for custom popover for each row.

```
<lightning-datatable
                   key-field="Id"
                   data={data} 
                   columns={columns}
                   onmouseout={hideData} 
                   onmouseover={showData}>
</lightning-datatable>
```

Comment: As far as I know you may have to create a custom data table.

Comment: yes that's the only solution I guess, Thanku